# Android CrossFader shows both layout

Tags: android, android-layout, cross-fade, materialdrawer

I'm using the Mike Penz GmailStyleCrossFadeSlidingPaneLayout. Only when the app starts I get the PartialView shown and a partial part of the FullView. It looks like they are layout above each other. But I just can click the icons from the PartialView.

Just when I start crossfading the partial view to full view every thing is okey and the partial view gets his "background color"

Do you have any idea why?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to the issue when the `SavedInstanceState` is not provided during the creation of the `CrossfadeDrawerLayout´ like shown here: https://github.com/mikepenz/Crossfader/blob/6d778720644c5c7bc19aabd79aa8c9c70fd2da37/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/crossfader/app/SimpleActivity.java#L130

```
crossFader = new Crossfader()
                .withContent(findViewById(R.id.crossfade_content))
                .withFirst(result.getSlider(), firstWidth)
                .withSecond(miniResult.build(this), secondWidth)
                .withGmailStyleSwiping()
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build()
```

**.withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)**

Comment: @fred vom jupiter may accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Hi mike thanks for your fast answer. It doesn't work. because i'm using the `com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.3.7@aar`library, and i can't use miniResult and result. Do i have to impelemt the material drawer library in addition?

Comment: @FredvomJupiter ah ok. just replace the view for "first" and "second" with your views. it was just a code sample from the sample app. also make sure you pass the savedInstance to the builder